# PHP/Imagick: Image only written if echo'd

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

The following PHP, when passed [this image](http://i91.photobucket.com/albums/k307/Jesdisciple/zc9vfo.png), writes 0 bytes to $cache (but works fine with all other known images).  If the echo just before the call to writeImage is uncommented, it works fine.  (The PHP is being run via `<?php exec('php -f thumb.php -- img=zc9vfo.png >output'); ?>` for unrelated reasons.)  If anyone can give me a hint for what to look into, that would be fantastic.

```
if(isset($argc) && (!isset($_GET) || empty($_GET))){
  for($i = 1; $i < $argc; ++$i){
    if(strpos($argv[$i], '--') === 0){
      $argv[$i] = substr($argv[$i], 2);
    }
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $argv[$i], 2);
    $_GET[$key] = $value;
  }
}

if(!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) || $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == ''){
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = /* ... */;
}

$name =& $_GET['img'];
if(!isset($name)){
  die('unspecified');
}

$pipe_name = realpath("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/lib/php/pipes") . "/$name";
if(!file_exists($pipe_name) && !posix_mkfifo($pipe_name, 0777)){
  file_put_contents('output', 'Pipe could not be created.');
  exit(1);
}
$pipe = fopen($pipe_name, 'r+');
if(!$pipe){
  file_put_contents('output', 'Pipe could not be opened.');
  exit(1);
}

function pipe($msg, $die=FALSE){
  global $pipe;
  fwrite($pipe, $msg . PHP_EOL);
  if($die){
    die($msg);
  }else{
    echo $msg;
  }
}

$w = 150;
$h = 114;

if(!file_exists($image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/' . $name)){
  pipe('invalid', TRUE);
}
$cache = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/thumbs/' . $name;
if(!file_exists($cache)){
  $thumb = new Imagick($image);
  $thumb->flattenImages();
  $quotient = min($thumb->getImageWidth() / $w,
                  $thumb->getImageHeight() / $h);
  $thumb->cropImage($w * $quotient, $h * $quotient, 0, 0);
  $thumb->scaleImage($w, $h);
//  echo $thumb->getImageBlob();
  $thumb->writeImage($cache);
}

pipe('success');

fclose($pipe);

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I apparently have a faulty installation of ImageMagick, IMagick, and/or libpng.  See this forum thread:
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18326

Answer (score 1):

You may be misusing [`flattenImages`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-flattenimages.php).  From the user notes:

> Note that the function returns an Imagick object and does not modify the existing object.

You also might be accidentally ignoring error states.  [`cropImage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-cropimage.php), [`scaleImage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-scaleimage.php) and [`writeImage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-writeimage.php) all return boolean true on success, and the first two throw exceptions on failure.

When it writes a zero-byte file, does `getImageBlob` also return zero bytes?  I see you've commented it out, so clearly you were poking at it a bit.

Comment: I can't find the user notes you read, just http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#layers which doesn't say anything about that.  Obviously that's a CLI option, but I didn't find an API reference other than the one you linked which actually states that it returns TRUE, not an Imagick object, on success.  When getImageBlob is called, it returns the image data as intended and the file is properly written to.  If getImageBlob is not called, the file is not written; either way a segfault is generated.  Regardless, see my own answer.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention the segfault earlier.  The "flattenImages" word in my answer (as well as all the other function names) are links to the respective PHP documentation pages, on which you may find the mentioned user notes.